# VSCode Settings.json is missing

Tags: python, scrapy, visual-studio-code

I'm following a tutorial and I'm trying to point vscode to my virtual workspace I had set up for Scrapy, but when I open settings in VSCode, Workspace Settings tab is not there next to User Settings tab. Also I tried to go to file manually by going to 
%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json 
which I got from here:
https://vscode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getstarted/settings/
but settings.json isn't in there.
How can I get this setting to appear or get to my settings.json file so I can make the necessary edits.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is this bug (or feature, actually) in VSCode where when you open User Settings in a tab, in a split pane (as long as it's not the right-most pane), the json settings button will not show up in upper right corner. Drag the tab into right-most pane[,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rU13Qbvu_g8) and it will. I get that this might not be the problem though, still...worth mentioning.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) for this sort of thing as it's up to date, the readthedocs version appears to be an out of date rip of the website from the past.

The path you mention `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json` is user settings, not workspace settings, *workspace* settings are located under the folder you have opened at `<folder>\.vscode\settings.json`. They don't exist by default but will be created when you open workspace settings and make some changes.

To open settings press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>, select the workspace settings button and change some settings:

[image]

You can access the actual file by clicking the button with the file icon in the top-right:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this did it!

Answer (score 7):

Just press CTRL + SHIFT + P, type `workspace settings` and press `ENTER`. If you want to see the json file, just press the `{}` button and vscode will automaticaly open or create the file in your workspace.

[VSCode Command Pallete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVEX7.png)

Comment: I've tried CTRL SHIFT +P, but workspace settings returns no results. The tab is nonexistent and I can't search for it

Answer (score 2):

It appears that coming in v1.44 will be command to open **workspace settings** - the editable json file - directly from the Command Palette.  See [No command to open workspace settings JSON #93189](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/93189)

[image: open workspace settings (json) from command palette]