# vscode where did the settings.json button go?

Tags: visual-studio-code

It seems the button to change the settings from the UI editor to json editor has moved somewhere and I can't find it. Where is it now? I simply want to migrate my settings from another computer and previously I have done so with copy&paste.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question is **very unclear** because you haven't provided any evidence on the disappearance of the settings.json button.

Comment: May be this could help https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55434687/vscode-settings-json-is-missing

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for?

[image]